# Use relative parent directory links in Apache httpd mod_autoindex

Tags: apache2, httpd

With Apache httpd mod_autoindex, the generated index pages use relative (without the leading slash) links for individual entries, for example:

```html
    <a href="failure/">failure/</a>
```

The "parent directory" link is absolute (includes the leading slash), though:

```html
    <a href="/project/2023-08-23/">Parent Directory</a>
```

Such behaviour breaks parent directory links in a reverse proxy setup.
This has been observed on Apache httpd 2.4.6.
Can the parent directory link be made relative with native httpd configuration (without rewriting the URL)?

Comment: I don't think mod_autoindex has an option for that. This Q&A has some useful approaches though: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9718284/2952385

Comment: Thanks, skimming those answers discusses removal of "parent directory" - any particular answer that would discuss the relative/absolute link?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a closer look, this might not be technically feasible.
A relative path in a subdirectory would be appended to the subdirectory.

For example, it would lead to incorrect paths like "/project/2023-08-23/project/".
This link could be "..", which works on Linux, but it might have other problems, especially cross-platform - and is not natively supported anyway.

For reverse proxying, rewriting this path in the generated HTML pages with mod_proxy_html might be the best option.